# Clarification need while parsing the jwt token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, okta

The Authorization server exposes the `JWKS` endpoint. So anyone can access the `JWKS` endpoint. The `JWKS` endpoint contains the details to construct the `public-key` which can then be used to verify the signature and extract the data.

Then, in this case,

1. Any client can access the jwks and verify the signature
2. Where is the private key in this flow? Is it on the OAuth server?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes to both questions. Only the Authorization Server can create tokens (using the private key) and then any application can verify them.

JWTs are most commonly verified by APIs, with a workflow like this:

- Decode the JWT and read the kid field from its header
- Download the JWKS keys and find the one that matches the kid in the received token - this value is usually then cached for performance reasons
- Then validate the JWT, checking it's signature, expiry, issuer and audience are all ok
- Then trust claims and scopes in the token and use them for authorization

See [this sample NodeJS code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenvalidation/jwtValidator.ts) for an example implementation, where it is recommended to use security libraries.